# update state of object and add it to state of array object in reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, state

i am want to make a form consisting of below input tags

```
 name:<input onChange={(e)=>handler(e)} value={temp.name} name="name"/>
 age: <input onChange={(e)=>handler(e)} value={temp.age} name="age"/>
 car:  <input onChange={(e)=>handler(e)} value={temp.car} name="car"/>
 <button onClick={(e)=>add(e)}>add</button>
```

i want this process=>when user types on any of this field the related state in below code be updated

```
 const [temp,tempchanger]=React.useState([
 {
  name:"",
  age:"",
  car:"",
  } ,
  ]),
```

i wrote the following code for it:

```
  const handler=(e)=>{
   const namex=e.target.name;
   const value=e.target.value;
  tempchanger(pre=>({...pre,[temp.namex]:value}))
  console.log(temp)
    }
```

but console.log shows the unaffected "temp",how can i do this?
also when i want that when i press add key the temp object be added to below state which is array of object...

```
  const [state,statex]=React.useState({list:[
 {name:"",age:"",car:""}
   ]})
```

please help me:

Comment: what is the `temp` intended to be in `temp.namex`? I think you meant `tempchanger(pre=>({...pre,[temp.namex]:value}))` to be `tempchanger(pre=>({...pre,[namex]:value}))`

Comment: Why do you have 2 different states for the same thing?

Comment: `useState()` is asynchronous. Your log runs before the state is updated. Create a `useEffect()` to do your logging and make it dependent on `temp`

Comment: @FireFighter i just define two different things for the same to be bring moe challenge and learn   more...

Comment: @RobinZigmond i add [namex]:value but still there is more error

Comment: You also wrapped your `temp` default in array braces `[]`